# Update shiny output from for loop inside observeEvent using reactiveValues

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to update a uiOutput using the change in `reactiveValues` from inside a loop, but it doesn't seem to work.
I've looked into some answers, but they're all trying to work it from inside output$somthing, which is not the case here:
like those:

[Update shiny output within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737226/update-shiny-output-within-loop)

[For loop inside output in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279376/for-loop-inside-output-in-shiny)

Here some reproducible app.

```
vars = reactiveValues(cc="",ct=0)
ui = fluidRow(uiOutput("warngt"),actionButton("searchgt","Search"))
server = function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$searchgt,{
    if(vars$ct<10){
      repeat{
        vars$ct=vars$ct+1
        vars$cc=paste(sprintf('<b style="color:blue">',"Searching...[%s]",vars$ct),"</b>");Sys.sleep(.5)
        #This also does not work:
        #output$warngt=renderUI({HTML(vars$cc)})
        vars$busca = try(print("Something"),silent = T)
        if(vars$ct==10){break}
      }
    }else{
      #This work just fine
      vars$cc=paste('<b style="color:red">',"Some warning.","</b>")
    }
    #This also doesn't work
    #output$warngt=renderUI({HTML(vars$cc)})
  })
  output$warngt = renderUI({HTML(vars$cc)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your understanding on how shiny works is incorrect. You cannot update UI in a loop because all renders/observers execute only after a previous observer get executed. The `repeat` loop doesn't work because that `observeEvent` is always occupying the session. You need to use `invalidateLater` instead. The following resources should help you solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244988/shiny-how-to-stop-processing-invalidatelater-after-data-was-abtained-or-at-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your sever codes to make it working.

You cannot update UI in a loop as I already mentioned in the comment, it isn't how Shiny works. Use `invalidateLater()` to do something similar to a for loop.

And also, `invalidateLater()` doesn't work in `observeEvent`, so you need to write the loop logic in `observe()`

`isolate()` is used to prevent recursive triggering of the observer, so it only re-evaluate every 0.5 second based on `invalidateLater(500)`

```r
server = function(input, output, session){
  vars = reactiveValues(cc="",ct=0)
  startSearch <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  startSearch <- eventReactive(input$searchgt,{
    TRUE
  })

  observe({
    req(startSearch())
    if (isolate(vars$ct) < 10){
      invalidateLater(500)
      isolate({
        vars$ct=vars$ct+1
        vars$cc=paste('<b style="color:blue">',"Searching...",vars$ct,"</b>")
        vars$busca = try(print("Something"),silent = T)
      })
    } else {
      vars$cc=paste('<b style="color:red">',"Some warning.","</b>")
    }

  })

  output$warngt = renderUI({HTML(vars$cc)})
}
```